# How to deploy the laravel in Windows server

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I have installed and run laravel in my windows server(hosted server) with the use of "php artisan serve" command. It worked well with "http:localhost:8000" inside the server but when I try with public url of server like "http:example.com:8000" it doesn't worked for me.

I couldn't understand.Inside the windows server worked fine but outside not working.

Also I checked the firewall with the 8000 port, no issue.

Answer (score 0):

edit hosts file and add domain to local

```
127.0.0.1 example.com
```